# Fixed aspect ratio and full (100%) height

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make a "full-height" (height : 100%) div with fixed aspect ratio?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: It's impossible because padding-left/right not depend of height parents element :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there are many ways to accomplish this, an easy one is to set both the width and height of a div relative to the viewport height using viewport units (VH).

```
div {
    width:40vh;
    height:100vh;
}
```

Another simple solution is to use a wrapper div with percentage padding as seen in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css).

Comment: Thank you.
It's all I need :)
padding-bottom not useful for me because it depend of the width.
I need depending on height.

Comment: @DmitryA. you are welcome! I believe you could also do the padding method with padding-right or padding-left to set the width relative to the height.